# Using VisualVM in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, visualvm

I have installed VisualVM (it can be seen in my eclipse plugins window). I am now trying to follow step 1 of section Usage mentioned [here](https://visualvm.java.net/eclipse-launcher.html).

My VisualVM preferences are set to :

- VM Executable: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/jvisualvm
- JDK   Home:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/

the jdk is the correct one

But I don't get the option 'Multiple Launchers available - select one.."

Answer (score 1):

You can change it using the Run configuration. On my eclipse it says at the bottom of the run Configuration "Using Eclipse JDT Launcher - Select Other".  Clicking "Select Other" will bring up the preferred Launcher where you can change defaults or update the settings.

**EDIT**

Here is an screenshot of an Eclipse Juno installation.

[image]

Comment: I don't see it in my Run Configuration. Do you mind taking a snaphshot and pasting it here( I could take a snapshot but this question will become useful to others if the snapshot of the correct setting is taken :))

Comment: @RAbraham added screenshot from Eclipse Juno which is the newest version I have access to at the moment

Comment: thanks! However I don't see it. I must have installed it incorrectly.Get back to you soon